# What's on /etc/nat folder in OS X Lion?

Tags: permissions, osx-lion, nat

As I tried to edit `/private/etc/nat/autoportmap.plist`, I accidentally modified permissions on the nat folder and asked Lion to apply it to enclosing items (I was giving myself write permission). As a result, I might have changed permissions for the enclosing files. Could anyone please confirm what are the permission sets by default for the three files present in this folder?

```
/private/etc/nat/autoportmap.plist
/private/etc/nat/natd.plist
/private/etc/nat/natd.plist.default
```

I'm using Lion Server.

Comment: I don't have that. What setting is responsible for creating that folder?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify I've got Lion server. I'm quite sure this is a server feature.